# Convert HTML to Pdf in Mule 4

Tags: anypoint-studio, mulesoft, cloudhub

Input payload has html content, which is to be converted to PDF using Mule 4. That PDF will be sent as an attachment to other end point. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Mule 4 doesn't have any built-in feature to transform to PDF. You should find a suitable Java library to generate the PDF and use the Java Module to invoke it, or some wrapper custom Java class.